# iOS AVAudioRecorder.record() returns false on device

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

`AVAudioRecorder.record()` returns `true` only first time after granting permission to microphone with system alert, than it always return `false`
. On simulator `.record()` always return `true`.
How to make AVAudioRecordenr record on the second and others app launch?

Here is the code:

```
func startRecording() {
        let dirPath =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let recordName = "record.wav"
        self.audioURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath + "/" + recordName)
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        let microPhoneStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.audio)
        print(microPhoneStatus)
            do {
                try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.duckOthers)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

            guard let recorder  = try? AVAudioRecorder(url: self.audioURL, settings: [:]) else {
                self.finishRecording(success: false)
                return
            }


            self.audioRecorder = recorder
            self.audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
            self.audioRecorder.delegate = self
            let prepare = self.audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
            try! session.setActive(true, options: [])
            let record = self.audioRecorder.record()
    }
```

Already tried adding `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` and requesting `AVAudioSession` `requestRecordPermission` from code:

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: the question is - how to make AVAudioRecorder record on the second and others app launch?

Comment: Does it help if you delete the old file before recording? `AVFoundation` doesn't like overwriting files in general.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman thats a good point, still it has no result

Comment: In simulator it works fine but we have to set AVAudioSessionCategory to make it work on device prior to recording.
For the solution please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024134/audio-is-playing-in-simulator-but-not-on-device#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two important things need to be done before recording audio.

1. The app needs to declare why/how recording is necessary. In `Info.plist` add a key for `Privacy - Microphone Usage Description` with a good textual description.
2. The app needs to request explicit user permission *before each* call to `AVAudioRecorder.record()`. Implement something resembling:

```swift
import AVFoundation

let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
session.setActive(true)
session.requestRecordPermission { granted in
    print(granted)
}
```

<sup>Note that this is a simplified sample. Additional do/try/catch error handling will need to be added as these methods are marked `throws`.</sup>